# Best performance to passing data between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I’am studying RxSwift and have this one case. 
From tableView cell, I go to info restaurant, and if I change the rate for this restaurant, I want to change this rate in tableView too, but I don’t want to update tableView, because restaurants are downloaded from the backend,  cause  restaurants data is not loaded every time when viewWillApear is called. Now I’m using cloujers, in prepareForSegue, I’m setting a new rate in cell from its info. I read that the cloujers are used in a lot of resources, can this be done with the help of RxSwift or another best way?

Comment: make your rate info as an observable, and bind your element in the cell on it. When you'll change the rate value your cell will be updated without reloading everything. Check out RxDataSources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best library to work with collection view and table view in RxSwift

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources